# My Tcp device does not accept unicode

Tags: c#

I have a string and I convert this string to byte array to send tcp device.

```
  byte[] loadRegionCommand=System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("$RGNLOAD http://1.1.1.1:9999/region1.txt");
```

`System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes()` method is adding a zero after each character.But propably my device doesnt accept unicode , what can I use instead of System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes().

[image]

Thanks for your help and best idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes()` method is adding a zero after each character.

Yes, because Unicode 16 bits, it is just what you asked for.

Use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` or maybe even `Encoding.ASCII`. That depends on what your device expects.

Comment: To be precise, `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` is UTF-16, which is *at least* 16 bits per code point.

Comment: Thank you , UTF8 solved my problem ,probably  my device accepts only ascii

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `UnicodeEncoding`. A unicode string string has a character size of two bytes. Since you are using input characters that are exclusively in the ASCII range, the upper byte will be always zero. The data is stored in little Endian, so the lower byte is written first. Hence your result.

You can choose a different encoding depending on your input. If all your characters are ASCII, use an `ASCIIEncoding`. If you *must*  use one byte per character and you have characters outside the ASCII range, use the appropriate code page. Otherwise you can use `UTF8Encoding`, which will encode all ASCII characters in one byte and all other charcters in two or more bytes (up to four).